# Why is `nil` discussed as boolean by treehouse?

Tags: ruby, boolean, computer-science

Why is `nil` considered a boolean or represented as a boolean value in the boolean tutorial for ruby? By definition, a boolean in computer science is a:

> data type, having two values (usually denoted true and false),
>   intended to represent the truth values of logic and Boolean algebra.

Comment: What is treehouse? You need to describe that.

Comment: @sawa, treehouse is some kind of a portal where you can subscribe to tutorials/video/learning materials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every expression in Ruby is being evaluated to an object and every object has a boolean value.

Many expressions can have a `false` value, but the only two objects in Ruby to have a boolean value of `false` are **`nil`** and **`false`**. That's why.

Comment: ahh, that makes perfect sense now

Answer (score 0):

What would be Ruby's counterpart to "true" and "false" in your quote are `true` and `false`, but as far as boolean logic in Ruby is concerned, `nil` behaves the same as `false`, and since only `nil` behaves like that besides `false` itself, `nil` is often assimilated with `false`.